# Lists AS value of a Map in Dart

Tags: list, maps, dart

I want to create a map of members, but every membres have 3 propreties : first name, last name, and username. How can I create like a list of liste, but with a map.

So I want to have something like :

```
var membres= {['lastname': 'Bonneau',
              'firstname': 'Pierre',
              'username': 'mariobross'],
              ['lastname': 'Hamel',
               'firstname': 'Alex',
               'username': 'Queenlatifa'],
            };
```

As you know, this code doesn't work. But it explain pretty well what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing the two constructs here.

Read this introduction to the language: http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#lists

A list is a list of elements which can be denoted with the shorthand `[...]` syntax:

```dart
var list = [1, 2, "foo", 3, new Date.now(), 4];
```

Whereas a map can be denoted with the curly brace shorthand syntax:

```dart
var gifts = {                         // A map literal
// Keys       Values
  'first'  : 'partridge',
  'second' : 'turtledoves',
  'fifth'  : 'golden rings'
};
```

So, let's modify your code to work:

```dart
var members = [
  {
    'lastname': 'Bonneau',
    'firstname': 'Pierre',
    'username': 'mariobross'
  },
  {
    'lastname': 'Hamel',
    'firstname': 'Alex',
    'username': 'Queenlatifa'
  }
];
```

You can, for example, print the information like this:

```dart
members.forEach((e) {
  print(e['firstname']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your intent correctly, you want to have a list of maps. What you have is correct except you confused `[` and `{`. The following works:

```
var membres = [
          {'lastname': 'Bonneau',
           'firstname': 'Pierre',
           'username': 'mariobross'},
          {'lastname': 'Hamel',
           'firstname': 'Alex',
           'username': 'Queenlatifa'}
        ];
```

As an example, to get a list of all usernames:

```
print(membres.map((v) => v['username']));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really need a `Map`, what about using a class to improve the structure of your code :

```dart
class Member {
  String firstname;
  String lastname;
  String username;
  Member(this.firstname, this.lastname, this.username);
}

main() {
  final members = new List<Member>();
  members.add(new Member('Pierre', 'Bonneau', 'mariobross'));
  members.add(new Member('Alex', 'Hamel', 'Queenlatifa'));
  // use members
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
// FirstName => LastName => Value
var lookup = new Map<String, Map<String, String>>();

// get / set values like this
void setValue(String firstName, String lastName, String value) {
   if (!lookUp.containsKey(firstName)) 
       lookUp[firstName] = new Map<String, String>();
   lookUp[firstName][lastName] = value;
}

String getValue(String firstName, String lastName) {
   if (!lookUp.containsKey(firstName)) return "";
   return lookUp[firstName][lastName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a map with value as list. Dont forget to initialize it
then if you want to fill it you first need to use built in function like `putIfAbsent` as in dart to add first object in list and then use `update` to add items in list. therefore you will need two arrays. First to put elements and then to add elements in list with same key. Also you can use try catch to identify if the key is present or not to do that in one loop

```
for (var item in days) {
    var date_time = DateTime.parse(item["date"] + " 00:00:00");
    _events[date_time] = _events.putIfAbsent(
        date_time,
        () => [
              {
                "title": item["title"],
                "date": item["date"],
                "time": reUse.get_time_am_pm_format(item["time"]),
                "feature": item["feature"],
              }
            ]);
  }
  for (var item in days) {
    var date_time = DateTime.parse(item["date"] + " 00:00:00");
    _events[date_time] = _events.update(date_time, (value) {
      value.add({
        "title": item["title"],
        "date": item["date"],
        "time": reUse.get_time_am_pm_format(item["time"]),
        "feature": item["feature"],
      });
      return value;
    });
  }
```